# Want to keep background fixed until a certain scrolldown point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two background photos, I want to show the first background photo if the page is not scrolled to 500, if the page is scrolled more than 500, then I want to show the second background, both backgrounds must be positioned fixed and stretched to the screen.

Only texts must move when page scrolls, and the background must change if the scoll is more than 500.

[**http://jsfiddle.net/2Pfsy/37**/](http://jsfiddle.net/2Pfsy/37/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var imageControl = function (event) {
            var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            url = null;
            console.log(fromTop);
            if (fromTop < 500) {
                url = 'http://i.hizliresim.com/KdrGVV.png';
            } else if (fromTop > 500) {
                url = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mHaVHhUegKs/UjHp6DruPeI/AAAAAAAAGx8/m_je_crr1v0/s1600/wp+cortana+screenshot+mashup.jpg';
            }

            $('body').css('background', 'url(' + url + ')');
        };
        $(window).scroll(imageControl);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2Pfsy/43/

updated your jsfiddle

changed background to `background-image` in js and added `background-attachment: fixed` in css

Comment: thanks, but when the page loads, I see a blank screen.

Comment: basically you'll want to set the first bg as a default (and changing it afterwards based on scroll)